# Sorting list of lists with mixed numerical values

Tags: python, list, sorting, numbers

Scenario: List containing 'rows' of list records with a variety of values

Problem: List.sort doesn't take the numeric values into consideration so values end up all over the place

i.e 9 is appearing in the list after 80

I've tried using

```
list.sort(key=operator.itemgetter[index])
```

and doing a

```
list.sort(lambda x,y:int(x[index])<int(y[index]))
```

to no avail.

Comment: What are the values in the list - we need more information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the converted number as the key.

```
L.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[index]))
```

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track, but operator.itemgetter is a function, so the syntax is:

```
list.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(index))
```

Or alternatively, use a lambda:

```
list.sort(key=lambda x: x[index])
```

The *key* parameter is the way to go, the *cmp* parameter has been removed in Python 3. If you want to use it anyway, you should use the *cmp()* built-in function to implement your comparator:

```
list.sort(cmp=lambda x, y: cmp(x[index], y[index]))
```

See also: http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/